# got error when run ng build --prod --base-href in angular 4

Tags: angular

Here is the error message when running `ng build --prod --base-href`

> ERROR in ./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css
>       Module build failed: BrowserslistError: Unknown browser major
>           at error (C:\Users\Gurpreet_Singh29\Practice Work\SOPID\SOP\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:37:11)
>           at Function.browserslist.checkName (C:\Users\Gurpreet_Singh29\Practice
>   Work\SOPID\SOP\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:320:18)
>           at Function.select (C:\Users\Gurpreet_Singh29\Practice Work\SOPID\SOP\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:438:37)
>           at C:\Users\Gurpreet_Singh29\Practice Work\SOPID\SOP\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:207:41
>           at Array.forEach ()
>           at browserslist (C:\Users\Gurpreet_Singh29\Practice Work\SOPID\SOP\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\node_modules\browserslist\index.js:196:13)
>           at C:\Users\Gurpreet_Singh29\Practice Work\SOPID\SOP\node_modules\postcss-merge-rules\dist\index.js:261:51
>           ...

How do I resolve this?

Comment: post your package.json file here

Answer (score 0):

Change bootstrap version to `"bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2"` in package.json if you are including it with npm or change urls to match that version.

The error is related to this bug ..

https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/9020

The error should not occur in the non-production build.

Comment: still the same error after changing version to "bootstrap": "4.0.0-beta.2"

Comment: Issue has been fixed in the latest angular cli. So change the version to 1.7.0 in package. json and do `npm install` that should fix it

Comment: Change the version of angular cli in package.json. Then run npm install.